# Grab the ID of a DIV Tag and then add some CSS style to the DIV accordingly

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to grab the ID of a DIV Tag and then add some CSS style to the DIV 
accordingly.
I am new to jQuery, and I am not sure if this is a good way to do it:

JavaScript:

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e){
    var whatid = $(this).attr('id');
    var whichDiv = "divName"+whatid;
    ("$(\"#"+whichDiv+"\")").addClass();
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myTest1" class="myClass">
  Helloworld I am new to JQuery 1
</div>
<div id="myTest2" class="myClass">
  Helloworld I am new to JQuery 2
</div>
```

Please advise.

---

What if I changed the code in this way:

JavaScript:

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e){
    var whatid = $(this).attr('id');
    var whichDiv = "divName"+whatid;
    ("$(\"#"+whichDiv+"\")").addClass();
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="myClass">CLick here 1</div>
<div id="2" class="myClass">CLick here 2</div>

<div id="myTest1">
  Helloworld I am new to JQuery 1
</div>
<div id="myTest2">
  Helloworld I am new to JQuery 2
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? Where does `"divName"` came from, and why do you think you need it?

Comment: @Kobi
Sorry, I was doing some self-learning about JQUery and this question came cross my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` already represents the div the user clicked on. You don't need to re-select it using jQuery since you already have a reference to it.

Simply, add the class to it:

```
$(this).addClass('someClass');
```

For your example:

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e) {
    // dont need to pull the id attribute
    // dont need to select the element again by id
    $(this).addClass('someClass');
});
```

And let's say if you need to select some element by `id` and `id` happens to be a variable, then this syntax is not valid:

```
("$(\"#"+whichDiv+"\")").addClass();
```

Here, you are creating a string, and then trying to call the `addClass` method on string, which doesn't exist. Also calling `addClass` without any parameters is useless, since you want to pass in the class name to add to the element here.

```
$("#" + whatid).addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Click Me</title>
    <style>
        .foo { 
            color:#F00;
            font-size:40px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('.myclass').click(function () {
                alert('you clicked this: ' + this.id);
                $(this).addClass('foo');
            });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mytest1" class="myclass">
        helloworld i am new to jquery 1
    </div>
    <div id="mytest2" class="myclass">
        helloworld i am new to jquery 2
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the selector is literally a concatenation of `"divName"` plus the ID of the element that you clicked, then try this:

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e){
    $("#divName" + this.id).addClass('someClassName');
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To match the HTML you provided, do the following, **but be aware that it may not work because it is invalid to start an ID with a number**.

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e){
    $("#myTest" + this.id).addClass('someClassName');
}
```

Instead, you should make your IDs valid by starting them with a letter, and adjust the paired element ID to match the change.